# Distance between 3 points using a generic class/methods

Tags: java, generics, coordinates, distance, point

I am supposed to return the distance from `(0,0)` to `this` point and the distance method should return the distance from `this` to `p`. I am new to Java and generic classes/methods. My distance method has an error but I think I am on the right track. The methods in `CharNumber` should return the value of the private field `aChar` and convert it to numerical values.

```
public class Point <T extends Number> {
  private T x;
  private T y;

  public Point(T x, T y){

  }

  public T getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public T getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public double radius(){
    return Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(x.doubleValue() - 0.0, 2)
            + Math.pow(y.doubleValue() - 0.0,2));
  }

  public double distance(Point p){
    return Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(this.x.doubleValue() - p.getX(), 2)
            + Math.pow(this.y.doubleValue() - p.getY(), 2));
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Point{"
        + "x=" + x
        + ", y=" + y + "}";
  }
}
```

---

```
public class CharNumber extends java.lang.Number {
  private char aChar;

  public CharNumber(char c){// FIXME: 10/10/16

  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "CharNumber{"
        + "aChar=" + aChar + "}";
  }

  @Override
  public int intValue() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public long longValue() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public float floatValue() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public double doubleValue() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

---

UPDATED POINT CLASS

```
 public class Point <T extends Number> {
private T x;
private T y;
public Point(T x, T y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

}

public T getX() {
    return x;
}

public T getY() {
    return y;
}
public double radius(){
    return   Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x.doubleValue()-0.0, 2)+Math.pow(y.doubleValue()-0.0,2));
}

public double distance(Point<Number> p){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x.doubleValue() - p.getX().doubleValue(),2)
            + Math.pow(this.y.doubleValue() - p.getY().doubleValue(),2));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point{" +
            "x=" + x +
            ", y=" + y +
            '}';
}
public static void main(String args[]){// FIXME: 10/10/16
    Point<Integer> p = new Point<>(1,1);
    Point<Double> p2 = new Point<>(2.5,3.4);
    Point<CharNumber> p3 = new Point(5,6);


    System.out.println(p);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(p3);
}
```

}
How do I call the distance and radius methods in my main method?

Comment: Use `p.getX().doubleValue()` and `p.getY().doubleValue()`.

Comment: Instead of this.x.doubleValue() - p.getX(),2?

Comment: Instead on using `p.getX()` you will need to use `p.getX().doubleValue()`. Similarly for Y values.

Comment: Be aware of the `hypot` method in the `Math` class.  It's often more accurate than all this squaring and square-rooting.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor must assign to the fields.

```
private final T x;
private final T y;

public Point(T x, T y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

And

```
private final char aChar;

public CharNumber(char c) {
    aChar = c;
}
```

And as commented:

```
public <U extends Number> double distance(Point<U> p) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x.doubleValue() - p.getX().doubleValue(), 2)
        + Math.pow(y.doubleValue() - p.getY().doubleValue(), 2));
}
```

or even

```
public <U extends Number> double distance(Point<U> p) {
    return Math.hypot(x.doubleValue() - p.x.doubleValue(),
        y.doubleValue() - p.y.doubleValue());
}
```

If the Point class is immutable, cannot change its coordinates, then the fields can be made final. That allows assigning variables to each other (sharing point values).

The Point parameter should be generically typed too.

There rests a couple of things, but that you know.

Comment: At the time your answer only had the first one.  I'll remove my comment.

Comment: I am not sure if we are supposed to finalize the variables... do they have to be finalized? I also am supposed to make a main that creates a Point with Integer values, one with Double values, and one with CharNumber values. Then print the toString return and the return from radius from the 3 points I created.

Comment: As long as you do not have methods like translate/move that change the fields, it would be nice. But I would leave `final` out, when not stressed in the course.